# how to correctly make template operator T() work with funcs like printf?

Tags: c++, templates, printf, encode

I'm working on auto encoding/decoding on MyVal class
something like

```
template<typename T>
class MyVal
{
public:
    MyVal() {}

    MyVal(T v)
    {
        encode(v);
    }

    operator T ()
    {
        return decode();
    }

    operator const T () const
    {
        return decode();
    }

    MyVal<T>& operator=(T& v)
    {
        encode(v);
        return *this;
    }
}
```

and I have

```
MyVal<int> some;
```

It works fine for most of the time but if I run `printf("%d", some)`, it won't call any T() so it won't give me the decoded value.

Is there any way to make printf works without changing any code out of MyVal class?

Comment: That's not how you do IO in C++. Look up C++ stream operators. http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c++-iostreams.html

Comment: No, this is not possible. Functions taking `...` do not perform any conversions on the arguments other than the default argument promotions.  In modern C++, avoid using functions with `...` in the parameter list (other than ones with template parameter packs!)

Comment: Use Boost Format for a printf-like experience with good C++ support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`printf` assumes that you, the programmer, are taking responsibility to pass the correct parameter types.  Since you are taking that responsibility, you can't rely on *automatic conversions*.

You must **manually** cast the variable to the correct type.

```
printf("%d", int(some));
```

Comment: I almost corrected myself for using a "C style cast" until I *took in the big picture*...

Comment: Even taking in the big picture, `some.operator const int()` avoids accidental narrowing conversions such as `long` -> `short`, `double` -> `int` etc..